# Change default browser linux - Python

Tags: python, linux

i want to change the default browser in ubuntu and the open a url

What is tried:

```
def makedefault():
    subprocess.call(('xdg-settings set default-web-browser google-chrome.desktop')
    webbrowser.get().open('http://google.com')
```

but it is launcing the url in firefox. Thanks for the help.

Btw when i run xgd command in terminal it changed the default url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `google-chrome` command to open a particular url in chrome via `subprocess`

`google-chrome www.google.com`

Note: If `google-chrome` is not in your `PATH` variable, use absolute path or add the path to `PATH` variable

Comment: @Thanks this helped me immensely :)